# In the symmetric group $S_{10}$, every element of order $14$ is odd permutation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that: In the symmetric group $S_{10}$, every element of order $14$ are odd permutations.

Comment: What are the possible cycle types of elements of order in $S_{10}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of a permutation is equal to the least common multiple of the lengths of its cycles. Since we can have no cycle of length $14$ in $S_{10}$, we see that the permutations of order $14$ must each be disjoint cycles, one of which is a **two-cycle**, and the other of which is a **seven-cycle**.

We have the product of a 2-cycle, which is odd (one transposition), and a 7-cycle, which is even (decomposes into the product of an even number of transpositions), so permutations of order $14$ must be (odd + even) = odd permutations.

Comment: Should we really be supplying detailed answers to such easy questions (particularly when they are worded as commands)?

Comment: @Derek Sometimes it really is okay to lighten up, yes?

Comment: Well, no. That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The only possible combination of cycles in $\;S_{10}\;$ whose lowest common multiple is $\;14\;$ is a transposition and a $\;7$-cycle , so...